# Can't get my backbone script to work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm fairly new to javascript, and completely new to backbone. What I am doing wrong? Why won't this work? Nothing will show, and the error message is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null in the underscore script.

```js
(function($) {

  var Session = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      title: ''
    }
  });

  var session1 = new Session({title: '1'});
  var session2 = new Session({title: '2'});
  var session3 = new Session({title: '3'});
  var session4 = new Session({title: '4'});

  var SessionList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '#',
    model: Session,
    localStorage: new Store("session-list-store")
  });

  var sessions = new SessionList();

  var SessionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: Session,
    tagName: 'li',
    template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),
    initialize: function () {
      this.render()
    },

    render: function () {
      var template = _.template($('#item-template').html(), {})
      console.log(template);
      this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.title));
      return this;
    }
  });

  var SessionListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: sessions,
    el: '#main',
    initialize: function () {
      this.template = _.template($('#session-list').html());
      sessions.fetch(); // Loads list from local storage
    },

    render: function () {
      this.$el.html('title');
      return this;
    }
  });

  sessionView = new SessionView();
  sessionListView = new SessionListView();

 })(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-8 sessions">
  <h2>Sessions</h2>
  <section id="main">
    <ul class="session-list"></ul>
  </section>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
    <div class="view"></div>
</script>
```

Comment: Cant reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/9r9pdf3w/ looks fine other than i dont know what `Store()` is

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Store is not defined`

Comment: You're creating the template function in 3 ways in your own code. 1) as a [template](http://backbonejs.org/#View-template) property of view (`template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),`) which I'd recomment. 2) as a variable in `render` (`var template = _.template($('#item-template').html(), {})`) I don't think this works in the latest versions of underscore 3) in the `initialize` (`this.template = _.template($('#session-list').html())`) refactor the code and be consistant...

Comment: Thanks guys, I resolved it :)

I've encountered a new problem now, though.. 

I can't get collection.pluck() to work and I have no idea why.

    var selItems = categoryList.where({marked: true});
                var sc = JSON.stringify(selItems);
                var ss = sc.pluck('category');

I get Uncaught TypeError: sc.pluck is not a function. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? @T ?